# CSS Change style without rewriting

Tags: html, css

When I have this html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1{
                color: green;
            }
            main{
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>I'm green!</h1>
        <main>
            <h2>I'm red!</h2>
            <h1>I also should be red!</h1>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can I make the second `h1` (inside `main`) red without writing: `main h1{color: red;}`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Better off writing `main h1 { color: red }` though.

*EDIT FROM COMMENTS*

For larger projects you can define base level styles for elements like `h1` and then get more specific with classes/id's when you need to: `h1#page-header`.

You can also try SASS which will allow you to use variables like `$main-color: #333;`. If you use this variable in your font styles like `p { color: $main-color}` and `h1 {color: $main-color}` you would only have to modify the `$main-color` variable.

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}

h1:last-child {
  color: red;
}

main {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>I'm green!</h1>
<main>
  <h2>I'm red!</h2>
  <h1>I also should be red!</h1>
</main>
```

Comment: The problem is: What do I do on bigger projects? (example) I have a project where I have a `standard.css` where standard values are defined. When I want to change (for example) `p` in `main` to be `white` but I have defined `p` as `red` in `standard.css` then I have to define every `p` in main to be `white`. But thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Myzel394 Well, IMO, first you should think on defining something like a "theme" for your site, in order to have some consistency throughout the whole site; after that you can create something like "modifiers" or "utilities" that just take care of special cases, these can be independent classes that you just add to the element you need them on... For Example: - All your `p` tags are defined on `standard.css` to be white; but you also have a `modifiers.css` where you have `.is-white {color: white}`, and then when you just add `<p class="is-white">` and only that one will be white

Comment: Then deal with the styles when your project is bigger. Make more specific styles. main h1 makes sense because it is the first and only h1 within the main container. If there are more containers, well you use the direct descendant selector '>' or give the container a style so you can target it specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class or id to the element you want to change style:

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}

main{
  color: red;
}

.specific-h{
  color: red;
}

</style>
```

```html
<h1>I'm green!</h1>
<main>
  <h2>I'm red!</h2>
  <h1 class="specific-h">I also should be red!</h1>
</main>
```

Or you could do it with the "id" tag:

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}

main{
  color: red;
}

#specific-h{
  color: red;
}

</style>
```

```html
<h1>I'm green!</h1>
<main>
  <h2>I'm red!</h2>
  <h1 id="specific-h">I also should be red!</h1>
</main>
```